# Copy data and paste as values

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My code currently copies rows of data from source workbooks to a Mastercopy excel. However, I would like to paste the values as number. Any idea on how I can go about modifying in the code below?

```
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String

FolderPath = "D:\Users\AlexPeteson\Desktop\Test File\Downloads\"

Filepath = FolderPath & "*.csv"

Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Dim erow

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 2), Cells(erow, 10))

Filename = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't paste anything, but the method to paste values is `Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Thanks for your response, do i replace the replace the entire string: ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 2), Cells(erow, 10))? I was experimenting with it but couldnt get it correct @Damian

Comment: Let me give you an edited code... wait some minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, edite the master sheet name on `Set ws = ...`

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyDataFromMultipleWorkbooksIntoMaster()

    Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wbTemp As Workbook, wsTemp As Worksheet

    'Define your master workbook and sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("YourMasterSheetName")

    FolderPath = "D:\Users\AlexPeteson\Desktop\Test File\Downloads\"

    Filepath = FolderPath & "*.csv"

    Filename = Dir(Filepath)

    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

    Dim erow As Long

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1) ' lets suppose it is always on the first sheet in the workbook

        With wsTemp
            'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
            lastcolumn = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
        End With
        'Find the last blank cell on your master sheet
        erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wbTemp.Close Savechanges:=False
        Set wbTemp = Nothing
        Set wsTemp = Nothing
        Filename = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Damian. I tried it but there is a run-time error '13' (Mismatch) at this line: Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1) ' lets suppose it is always on the first sheet in the workbook. My source workbooks only have 1 tab where the sheet name is dynamic i.e. it includes a timestamp. Not sure if it is causing the error. @damian

Comment: Sorry @AlexPeteson my mistake! I've defined wsTemp As Workbook, it should be Worksheet!

Comment: Hi @damian so that's how its suppose to work. I added the Application.DisplayAlerts = False to disable the prompt as well. Thanks so much, learnt something new today.

Comment: What you must look up on your learning is how to always work with worksheets and workbooks references... that way your code will have much less errors. Since you are always telling excel where are you taking data from and where to put it, `ActiveCell` or `ActiveSheet` as well as `ActiveWorkbook` can fail way too much depending on the user clicking things... this way you are saving a lot of time checking for errors.